# Epplus get the column header

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, epplus

I would like to understand how to get the column letter using Epplus. I know that Address will return the column letter and row number and FullAddress will add the sheet name but I don't see an object for just the column letter.

```
?sheet.Cells[index2, index3].Address
"J2"

?sheet.Cells[index2, index3].FormulaR1C1
""

?sheet.Cells[index2, index3].FullAddress
"'Sheet1'!J2"

?sheet.Cells[index2, index3].FullAddressAbsolute
"'Sheet1'!$J$2"

?sheet.Cells[index2, index3].Rows
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

EPPlus contains a `ExcelCellAddress` class which has the static method `GetColumnLetter` to retrieve the letter corresponding to the supplied 1-based column index.

```
public static string GetColumnLetter(int column)
```

The following call will return column letter `A`.

```
String columnLetter = OfficeOpenXml.ExcelCellAddress.GetColumnLetter(1); // A
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. This helped me. Thanks!

Comment: I am probably using an older version (back when it was still free), but the method name for me was GetAddressCol(int Column).  This answer set me in the right direction though.

Answer (score -2):

You already know index3.  You have the column letter with this.

```
public static class IntExtension
{
    public static string ToExcelColumn(this int i)
    {
        string column = string.Empty;

        if (i / 26m > 1)
        {
            int letter = (int)i / 26;
            column = ((char)(65 + letter - 1)).ToString();
            i -= letter * 26;
        }

        column += ((char)(65 + i - 1)).ToString();

        return column;
    }
}
```

Simply call `index3.ToExcelColumn();`

Comment: This is limited to `A` through `ZZ`.  Would make more sense to do this recursively.  `XFD` is the final (normally) addressable column in Excel.